# Take out specific, unwanted values in a column

Tags: r

I am new to R and I have a question concerning how to remove specific values in a column.

In my situation, I have a column of latency.  But in every other row, there is a latency that corresponds to a trial/row ("test instruct") that I want to ignore. How would I select these specific latencies and get rid of them in the column? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have included a picture of the data frame below for easy reference. I have underlined the columns, "trialcode" and "latency" that I am discussing in green. I then underlined the latency that I would like to get rid of in red and the latency I would like to keep in the column in blue.

[image: Picture of data frame in question]

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean by removing values from the column - setting them to NA? Remove the entire rows? `df <- subset(df, trialcode != "testinstruct")` would remove the rows (if the data.frame you show was called `df`), while `df[df$trialcode == "testinstruct",]$latency <- NA` would set the latency of the rows where trialcode is "testinstruct" to NA, for example.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a coding service. Please read the following documentation, then [edit] and rephrase the question. [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) & [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Always [Provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example (e.g. code, data, errors) as text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) & you're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Answer (score 0):

You can see this example below

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(trialcode = c("testinstruct", "DemBI_O", "testinstruct"), latency = c(1039, 658, 445))
#       trialcode latency
# 1 testinstruct    1039
# 2      DemBI_O     658
# 3 testinstruct     445

df2 <- df %>% 
  filter(trialcode != "testinstruct")

#   trialcode latency
# 1   DemBI_O     658
```